# C# Expression tree, using expression with static type of expression for lambda invocation

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I am stuck trying to make the dictionary values generic in the following code. I would like to use `Expression` as a dictionary key and not `Expression<Action>`. If I change the code to use `Expression` I get an error. It would be great if the solution would involve `Expression.Convert` so I would not be trying to make an `Expression` generic by adding `Action` as a generic parameter.

```
Expression<Action> test = () => Console.WriteLine("Hello world");

var dict = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Action>> {["foo"] = test};

var functionDef = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(dict), "Item", Expression.Constant("foo"));

var intermediate = Expression.Lambda(functionDef);

Expression.Invoke(Expression.Invoke(Expression.Constant(intermediate)));
```

Error if I use generic `Expression` instead of `Expression<Action>` as a dictionary type:

> Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression' cannot be invoked (Parameter 'expression')

Comment: What makes you think that there IS an expressible conversion between `Expression<Action>` and `Expression`?

Comment: There is not indeed. But I was hoping C# built-in Expression compiler would not care about static type being `Expression` and only care about runtime type which is `Expression<Action>`.

Comment: @DavidL Because `Expression<Action>` inherits from `LambdaExpression` which inherits from `Expression` (IIRC there are a few more steps along the way as well). So any `Expression<Action>` should be assignable to an `Expression`.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `Expression.Invoke`? If you're trying to actually invoke the expression, that's not what `Expression.Invoke` does; it creates an `InvocationExpression` using a `LambdaExpression` and the parameters to be passed into the `LambdaExpression` (if any), but it doesn't actually execute any code. `Expression` and all the types that inherit from it, represent a description of executable code. In order to actually execute the code, you have to call `Compile` on a `LambdaExpression`; and on the resulting delegate instance, you can call `Invoke`.

Comment: The inheritance hierarchy for .NET expression trees is a little confusing here: `Expression<TDelegate>` (including `Expression<Action>`) inherits from `LmabdaExpression` which in turn inherits from `Expression`. A `Dictionary<string, Expression>` should have no trouble holding an `Expression<Action>` as the value. Also, I'm not sure why you refer to using `Expression` as the key of the dictionary, when the key is `string`; it's the value that is `Expression` or `Expression<Action>`.

Comment: @ZevSpitz Thanks for the comment. I was able to get around this problem with a hacky solution: https://github.com/amir734jj/csharp-lisp/blob/master/Core/LipsToExpression.cs#L251

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see the connection between the code you referenced and this question.

Comment: Sure. Happy to explain. I have a "Contour" which is a `Dictionary<String, Expression>`. I was writing a mini LISP compiler and in LISP we can pass a function as a parameter to the function. Then inside the body of the function, I go look at my contour and grab the expression by name. Hopefully, the user knows what they are doing and passed a function as a parameter. Then I want to call that `Expression`. But we know that we can't just call it because it has a static type of `Expression` but in reality, it is a `LambdaExpression` (i.e. its dynamic type). Then at this point I asked this question

Comment: But C# apparently doesn't allow us to simplify invoke that `Expression` and I get the above error. So, to fix the problem I have to add those casts to correct the type of the expression and all works now.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what you're issue here is, but maybe you don't need expressions.

Here is an expression-less example:

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, Action<string>>() 
{
    { "hello", name => Console.WriteLine($"Hello {name}") },
    { "bye", name => Console.WriteLine($"Bye {name}!. Have a great day!") }
};

d["hello"]("Node.JS");
d["bye"]("Node.JS");
```

This prints:

```
Hello Node.JS
Bye Node.JS!. Have a great day!
```

Comment: I need to use `Expressions`. I am writing a toy LISP compiler in C# that converts LISP to C# expression-tree https://github.com/amir734jj/csharp-lisp/blob/master/README.md